# Passing a value from bootstrap data-id to a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a dropdown menu with several months values. This is an example of one of them.

```
<li data-toggle="modal" data-id="January" class="random " href="#AddMonth">January</li>
```

I would like to pass the "January" value to a php variable. Something like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AddMonth" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update your information</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <?php
         // $month  = ? // month will contain the variable that was pass from data-id
         MethodSendMonthData($month);

       ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure how could I achieve this?

Comment: `PHP is a server-side language` while `HTML is client-side`. Meaning you can't pass the `data-id` from the selection to a php variable without the means of javascript, namely an ajax request.

Comment: How could I do it with an ajax request? or is it anywhere online I could check on how to do it?

Comment: @user3530310 The search box is at the top right of the page. Google may also have about 80 million search results for you, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment previously.

You can use [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) or even [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) to achieve this.

For examples sake, your element has an id of **`mymonth`**

```
<li id="mymonth" data-toggle="modal" data-id="January" class="random " href="#AddMonth">January</li>
```

Now with jQuery you could get the trigger:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li#mymonth', function(){
    // get month
    var val = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.post('myphpfile.php', {month: val}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

As you can see, we grab the attribute `data-id` and store it in the `val` variable. Then post it off to the example php file : `myphpfile.php`

The **`myphpfile.php`** would have your php function as such (example of course):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['month'])) {
    // do your sanatizing and such....
    // do your php stuff
    MethodSendMonthData($month);

   // you can echo back what you need to and use that in jquery as seen above
}

?>
```